# My jquery is not adding div to correct node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var out = [];
out.push('<div class="newData">');

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    out.push('<img src="' + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + '"/>');
    count++;

    // if (data.pagination.next_url = "") flag++;

    if (count > 4) {
        myurl = data.pagination.next_url;
        count = 0;  
    }

    out.push('</div>'); 
    $('#wrap').append(out);
```

I have this simple code but in inspect elements it shows.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="newdata"></div> 
    <img scr='"asd"/>
    <img scr='"asd"/>
    <img scr='"asd"/>
</div>
```

Why is is immediately closing the `newdata` div and why not putting photos in it?

Comment: Where does your for loop end? Please show us the entire for loop otherwise we cannot really help.

Answer (score 5):

Try using a string ,don't forget to close the for loop

```
var out = '';
out+='<div class="newData">';

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    out+='<img src="' + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + '"/>';
    count++;

    // if (data.pagination.next_url = "") flag++;

    if (count > 4) {
        myurl = data.pagination.next_url;
        count = 0;  
    }
}
    out+='</div>'; 
    $('#wrap').append(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the div `'<div class="newData">'` start outside the for loop and you close it inside the for loop. Then you add it inside the loop. Make sure you add valid html when you append it to #wrap, then it will work.

Edit: Additionally as others have pointed out: use strings to add the strings to each other and then append.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you can only append whole elements to the DOM. When you append the opening `div` tag, the browser will automatically close it for you. This means your `img` elements are then created as siblings.

You could instead change your logic to create the `div` container, then build the HTML string in a loop and append that together. Try this:

```
var $div = $('<div class="newData"></div>').appendTo('#wrap');
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    html += '<img src="' + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + '"/>');
}
$div.append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the loop, that causing you the problem

```
out+='</div>'; 
$('#wrap').append(out);
```

add this in last of your loop